# How to marginalise this?

Tags: probability

I came across this example in one of my lectures, but am unable to figure out how to carry out the marginalisation over c. In the context of bayesian networks:

[image]

For the first expression, it is obtained by reading the conditional independence assertations from the graph:

$p(ABC) = p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)$

From the LHS of the first expression we can get:

$\Sigma_cp(ABC) = p(AB)$

But for the RHS of the first expression how to we get from:

$\Sigma_c(p(A)p(C|A)p(B|C)) = p(A)p(B|A)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The marginalization is just another form of applying the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):
\begin{align}
 & p(a, b) \\
=& p(a)p(b|a) \tag{1} \\
=& p(a)\sum_c p(b, c|a) \tag{2} \\
=& p(a)\sum_c p(b|c, a)p(c|a). \tag{3} \\
=& p(a)\sum_c p(b|c)p(c|a). \tag{4}
\end{align}

This completes the proof. Note that $(1)$ -- $(3)$ hold for three arbitrary random variables, whereas the correctness of $(4)$ must rely on the given graphical model specification.

---

Explanations:

$(1)$:  Using the definition of conditional probability.

$(2)$:  The event $\{B = b\}$ can be expressed as $\{B = b\} = \bigcup_c (\{B = b\}\cap\{C = c\})$.  This is essentially the same as deriving the law of total probability.

$(3)$:  Apply the definition of conditional probability again to verify $p(b, c|a) = p(b|c, a)p(c|a)$.

$(4)$:  For the given the graphical model, $A$ and $B$ are independent conditional on $C$, whence $p(b|c, a) = p(b|c)$.

Comment: ah my bad, i added more information regarding the context for my question

Comment: Given the more context you added, $p(b|c, a) = p(b|c)$ is guaranteed, so the answer I posted actually already solved your question.

Comment: From $(4)$ to $(3)$, all you need to show is $p(b|c, a) = p(b|c)$, but this is exactly the definition of $A\perp B|C$, which is what the graph tells you.

Comment: OHH ok, so it means that i have to take into the assumptions already made in the graphical model for the derivation?

Comment: @DariusYip Of course... Without the graph, it is not always true (that is, $p(b|c, a) = p(b|c)$ does not always hold.  Check the first version of this answer).